# QGIS: Is it possible to merge two stacked raster layers keeping color rendering and transparency?

Tags: qgis, raster, layers, transparency-opacity, qgis-3

Extremely new to QGIS and was hoping to merge 2 layers and maintain an "overlay" keeping layer transparency and color rendering?

I seem to loose the top layers layer properties when merging and it reverts to it's original look.

Before "Merge":
[image: Hopeful outcome]

After "Merge":
[image: Actual Outcome]

Using QGIS 3.2.2

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the old_layer>Styles>Copy and them right clicking on the merged_layer>Styles>Paste? Or is it more than just a style issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by exporting the view of your rendered image from Project → Import/Export → Export map to image:

[image]

If you want to the extent of your output image to have the same extent of a specific layer, you can choose from one of the layers (Calculate from layer). In the following example I chose ShadedRelief and put 90 in the resolution because I am keeping the same resoution of the original DEM. Keep world file selected, and save the output file.

Here is the input file, I selected Overlay `Multiply` and transperency of `50%` and exported the image:

[image]

Output rendered georeferenced image:

[image]